# Запуск activity из уведомления

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, android-notification

Задача открыть экран из уведомления (пусть экран D), при этом если приложение уже запущено и стек выглядит как A-B-C, то D должен поместиться поверх С, то есть будет A-B-C-D. Если приложение закрыто, то после открытия уведомления стек должен быть A-D.

Мне пришла идея запускать из пуша только А (который является singleTask), и в нем запускать либо в onCreate, либо в onNewIntent экран D. Проблема в том случае, когда приложение запущено и находится на экране С. Запуск D затирает экраны B и С, стек снова выглядит как A-D. Пробовал запускать D c флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK - не помогло.

Есть ли способ запустить из A экран D, поверх существующего стека?

P.S. Возможно есть и другие способы решить задачу, но идей больше нет.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362124/3212712) и [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) - вроде как можно вручную стэк собрать